# БЭМ в VSCode - как задать настройки для сниппетов?

Tags: html, css, emmet, visual-studio-code

Использую БЭМ в модификации Николаса Галлахера (.block__element--modificator)

По умолчанию для БЭМ в VSCode используются сниппеты вида:

```
.block>.-element
```

Как можно заменить их на

```
.block>._element
```

В настройках пробую вариант

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "filters": "html, bem"
    }
},
"emmet.preferences": {
    "bem.elementSeparator": "__",
    "bem.modifierSeparator": "--",
    "bem.shortElementPrefix": "_",
},
```

Не помогает.

.block>._element выдает

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block block--element"></div>
</div>
```

вместо

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="block__element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: аналогичная проблема.
ответа на этот вопрос так и не нашел.

Comment: Emmet не пробовал выключать?
Я думаю из-за него

Answer (score 0):

Нужно писать так

.block>._element|bem

постфикс `|bem` включает в процесс фильтр Emmet 'html, bem'
чтоб Emmmet понял куда вставлять сепаратор блок__элемент нужно иметь не block, а класс блока, ибо bem это работа с классами.
аналогично,,, чтобы вставить сепаратор элемент--модификатор, следует впереди иметь конструкцию блок__элемент..

А вот написать блок--модификатор, а такую запись bem предусматривает уже не получится. таккак emmmet решит, что после блока должен идти элемент и и все равно сделает блок__элемент

Вот как я решаю эти проблемы:

```
.post>.-header+.-content--mod+footer.elem--mod|bem
<div class="post">
  <div class="post__header"></div>
  <div class="post__content--mod"></div>
  <footer class="elem--mod"></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, замените картинку кодом как текст.